# Cypher queries as batch operations on Neo4j

Tags: php, rest, neo4j, cypher

I need to run this type of queries in PHP:

```
START n = node($thisUser), m = node($userId)
MATCH n-[r:RATED]->m
WHERE r.skillId = $id
RETURN id(r)
```

There are a lot of them for a single page (~30). Since it's using REST, the run-time comes out not applicable (~5-10 seconds). So I'm trying to send them in a single batch but I cannot find any method to send actual cypher queries through REST as operations in a single batch.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

a) the [transactional rest resource](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html)
b) [batching](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html) multiple calls to the `/db/data/cypher` resource via the `/db/data/batch` resource, with `"to":"/cypher"` in the payload
c) passing collections instead of single values as parameters