# can I add a cypher query in batch in neo4jphp?

Tags: php, rest, neo4j, neo4jphp

can I add a cypher query in batch in neo4jphp? It seems to be possible with REST api?
[Ref1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/W93u4dTwg84)
[Ref2 Answer bullet-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997038/cypher-queries-as-batch-operations-on-neo4j)

I see transactions are possible with cypher queries but i need batch specifically since i need to combine  cypher queries with FT index additions/removals.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in the current version of neo4jphp. If you would like it to be, please file an issue in the Github repo https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/issues